# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(kx)=f(x)$. Show that if $f$ is continuous at $0$ then $f$ is a Constant function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ , there is $k \in \mathbb{R}$, $|k|\ne 1$, so that for every $x\in \mathbb{R} , f(kx)=f(x).$
>
> Show that if $f$ continuous at $0$ then $f$ is a constant function.

---

I tried to find something to show it from the definition of continuous function
but I didn't know how to continue.

We have that $f$ continuous at $0$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $|x-0|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$

And if $f$ not continuous on $0$ is $f$ still a constant function?

Comment: Suppose $0<k<1$. Note that $f(x)=f(kx)=f(k^2x)= f(k^3x)= ...$. These converge to $0$, so you have (by continuity) that $f(x)=f(0)$.

Comment: Not the same but similar and related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111361/solutions-of-the-functional-equation-f2x-fracfxx2/1111406#1111406

Comment: $|k|\ne 1$.....

Comment: You are reminded to use tag that describes the questions. Your question is not about "functions", although your question has a function $f$ in it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some hints:

0) Deal with the case $k=0.$

We now assume that $k\neq 0$.

1) prove that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, you have $f(x)=f(x/k)$.

2) Deduce you may assume $\vert k\vert<1$.

Assume for the rest of the proof  that  $\vert k\vert<1$.

3) Show that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and all integer $n\geq 1$, you have $f(k^nx)=f(x)$.

4) Conclude using continuity at $0$.

Comment: How would we achieve 2)? How could we deduce we may assume $|k| < 1$ and what do you exactly mean by that? What is the relevance? Thank you!