# Proving that if $f(x)=f(e^tx),$ then, $f$ is a constant function

Tags: calculus, functions, contest-math

This question was asked in an entrance examination for ISI (Indian Statistical Institute):

Q. If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $f(x)=f(e^tx)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t≥0,$ show that $f$ is constant.

I am aware that this question has been asked before on this site [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3226508/given-f-is-continuous-and-fx-fetx-for-all-x-in-mathbbr-and-t-ge0) I do understand the proofs given there, but I want to see if my method is right.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$

I want to begin by proving a much stronger result. My claim is that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $f(x)=f(ax)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and some $a$ such that $|a|≠1,$ then, $f$ is constant. We have a few cases to consider.

$\textbf{Case 1:}$

Let $a=0.$ Then, $f$ is trivially a constant function as $f(x)=f(0)\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$

$\textbf{Case 2:}$

Let $0<a<1.$ Then, $f(x)=f(ax).$ Now, take $y=ax$ to get $$f(y)=f(ay)=f(a^2x)=f(ax)=f(x).$$ In general, for $n\in\mathbb{N}, f(x)=f(a^nx).$ Now, we take the limit as $n$ goes to $\infty.$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a^nx)=f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}a^nx\right)=f(0).$$ I used the continuity of $f$ to take the limit inside the argument. Hence, $f(x)=f(0)\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$ Hence, $f$ is a constant function.

$\textbf{Case 3:}$

Let $a>1.$ Then, we apply a very similar argument. This time, we take $f(x)=f\left(\frac{x}{a^n}\right),n\in\mathbb{N},$ and then take the limit as $n$ goes to $\infty.$

$\textbf{Case 4:}$

Let $-1<a<0.$ This time, we let $f(x)=f(a^{2n}x),n\in\mathbb{N},$ and then take the limit as $n$ goes to $\infty.$ We could have also made the exponent $2n+1,n\in\mathbb{N}.$ At the end of the day, we want the exponent $k$ to be such that the parity of $a^k$ remains constant.

$\textbf{Case 5:}$

Let $a<-1.$ This time, we take $f(x)=f\left(\frac{x}{a^{2n}}\right),n\in\mathbb{N},$ and then take the limit as $n$ goes to $\infty.$ Again, the exponent being even is an arbitrary choice.

$\textbf{Conclusion:}$

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $f(x)=f(ax)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and some $a$ such that $|a|≠1,$ then, $f$ is a constant function.

Applying this conclusion to $f(x)=f(ex)$ as given in the ISI question, we get that $f$ is constant.

Is my conclusion right? Is my method right?

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2665791/42969

Comment: You can restrict to $a>0$ just by noting that if $a<0$ then $f(a^2x)=f(x),$ so $a'=a^2$ works and if $|a|\neq 1,$ then $|a'|\neq1.$

Comment: Essentially, you can reduce to the case $0<a<1.$

Comment: @MartinR, yeah that answer is very similar to mine. How did you find that question, btw? I looked up my question and didn't find a similar question on MSE, and that's why I thought it appropriate to ask here.

Comment: Your proof is fine, other than it can be made simpler. You can reduce your cases to $a=0$ and $0<a<1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, yes, I suppose that's what I essentially did. I made my proof so detailed because I was trying to convince myself it was right.

Comment: Also for the purpose of the question you only need the $a>1$ case, as $\exp t >1$ for all $t> 0$.

Comment: @aqualubix: Found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(x)%3Df(ax)%24). – See [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265/42969), in particular [How to search with Approach0](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/42969).

Comment: I may be wrong, but when you divide by $a^{2n}$, and later put $a = e$, you're just letting $t<0$?

Comment: @DS, I don't understand. The question says that $f(x)=f(e^tx)$ for all $t≥0.$ This also implies that $f(x)=f(ex).$ Using what I proved in my post, we conclude that $f$ is constant. I did not let $t<0.$ In fact, I used the particular case of $t=1.$

Comment: I'm not an expert, so don't take my word for it. But for case $3$ you say : $f(x) = f(\frac x{a^n})$ where $n$ is positive. Later you use $a = e$. $f(x) = f(\frac{x}{e^n}) = f(e^{-n}x)$, which was not given by the question. I feel this is just a workaround to assume $t<0$.

Comment: @DS, yes, you are right. It is a workaround. It was not explicitly given in the question that $f(x)=f(e^{-n}x),$ but it follows pretty easily from what is given in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Abezhiko's answer is very nice, I think that there is a simpler solution...

It is easy to see that the function $f(t) = e^t$ has the range $[1, +\infty) \ \forall t \ge 0$. Thus, let $k = e^t$ and note that $k$ can have every possible (real) value from $1$ to $\infty$. This gives: $f(x) = f(kx)$, which has to hold $\forall x \in \mathbf{R}, \forall k \ge 1$. This, however, gives that we can show that $f(x) = f(a) \ \forall x \in \mathbf{R} \ \forall a \in \mathbf{R}$. Hence, $f(x)$ has the same value $\forall x \in \mathbf{R}$, and is thus a constant function; $f(x) = c, c \in \mathbf{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a perhaps less common but elegant way to proceed.

Let's define the function $\phi(x) = e^tx$ and denote the corresponding composition operator by $C_\phi$, i.e. $C_\phi(f) = f\circ\phi$. It is easy to check that $C_\phi$ is a linear operator; in consequence the problem of finding $f$ such that $f(x) = f(e^tx)$ is equivalent to determining the eigenfunctions of $C_\phi$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$.

Lie theory permits to represent this composition operator as $C_\phi = e^{tx\partial_x}$; therefore, it possesses the same eigenvectors as its generator, namely $x\partial_x$. Those are characterized by the relation $x\partial_x f_\mu(x) = \mu f_\mu(x)$, where $\mu$ corresponds to the eigenvalue of $x\partial_x$, hence $f_\mu'(x) = \frac{\mu}{x}f_\mu(x)$ and by seperation of variables $f_\mu(x) = Ax^\mu$, with $A$ a constant.

Now, noticing that $C_\phi(f_\mu)(x) = f_\mu(e^tx) = A(e^tx)^\mu = e^{t\mu}f_\mu(x)$, in other words that the eigenvalues of $C_\phi$ are given by $\lambda = e^{t\mu}$, we want $\lambda = 1$, hence $\mu_k = 2\pi ik/t$, and $f_{\mu_k}(x) = Ax^{2\pi ik/t}$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since we are only interested in reals functions, the only solution corresponds to the case $k=0$, hence $f(x) = A = const$. *QED*.

Comment: You lost me at "linear operator", but this seems to be an interesting answer for future visitors of this page to refer to.

Comment: @aqualubix  I must concede that this method may be seen as "heavy machinery" for such problems, but as you said, it might be useful to a future visitor.

Comment: @Abezhiko could you look through my solution perhaps, as it seems far too simple to me...